# Unload Dll dynamically

Tags: winapi, dll, d

I've tried my best to convert an injected Dll from C++ to D and came to that point where I want to unload the Dll dynamically, when F7 gets pressed. 
In C++ it was simple to use `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` to let the Dll unload itself, but the method doesn't seem to work when used in the D Dll.
Here you can see the working C++ code:

```
// Module.cpp
void Module::QuitThread()
{
    while (true) {
        // KeyPress
        if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7) & 0x8000) != 0) {
            break;
        }

        Sleep(1);
    }

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(Module::_hDllModule, 0);
}
```

I know this is the quick and dirty way, but it's enough for now. Here is the D equivalent:

```
// module.d
private void quitThread()
{
    while (true) {
        // KeyPress
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7) & 0x8000) {
            break;
        }

        Sleep(1);
    }

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(_hModule, 0);
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? How am I supposed to unload the D Dll?

Comment: There's nothing specific to D in this code. You may try to terminate the runtime before calling FreeLibrary. (`core.runtime.Runtime.terminate();`).

Comment: Calling `core.runtime.Runtime.terminate();`before `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` causes the host process to crash.

Comment: what's programmed in D, the host or the dll ?

Comment: The Dll's programmed in D

Comment: You are confusing WinAPI and D here. If you have Win32 DLL handle, you can unload it using win32 API at any time no matter what. Read D manuals.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I have a Win32 Dll handle and try to unload it via the Win32 Api. This works in my C++ Dll but not in the Dll written in D. The provided code examples demonstrates the equality of both code sections.